# Drush clear cache without the codebase

Tags: drush, database, caching

Is possible to clear the cache using drush (or else?) when I don't have the codebase anymore.

Here is the use case: I deleted the codebases of a lot of sites with backing up. Now I'm going to backup and delete the databases but I forgot to clear the caches before deleting the codebases. Now its too much work to restore all the sites one by one and clear the caches and do everyting again.

Comment: Drush needs to bootstrap Drupal. If you removed all the Drupal files, Drush cannot do anything.

Comment: do you know another way without the codebase?

Comment: its strange, but clear tables:
cache, cache_* and ctools_object_cache and ctools_css_cache

Comment: It doesn't make sense, since without code you could delete all the database tables, which are not going to be used.

Comment: I couldn't make myself clear. I am backing up the databases. And all code is already backed up and deleted (bad desicions, ok.). But then I remember that I should have cleared the caches to reduce sqldump sizes and overhead while restoring.

Comment: Oooh... now it's clear. I was struggling to understand the need of deleting tables without the code that would use them. :D